# How to plot a triangular pyramid in matlab with 4 vertex in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, 3d, surf

After thousands trials, Im not able to 3d plot a pyramid using 4 vertex using surf.

This is the best approach that I have found in matlab forum, but in my case I need to input those values and not be fixed as it is in the link.

[https://es.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/556651-how-to-plot-three-dimensional-triangular-based-pyramid][1]

Please, can someone help me?

this is my best try, or I think so! Im doing it in appdesigner

```
            P1=[app.UITable.Data(1,1),app.UITable.Data(1,2),app.UITable.Data(1,3)];
        P2=[app.UITable.Data(2,1),app.UITable.Data(2,2),app.UITable.Data(2,3)];
        P3=[app.UITable.Data(3,1),app.UITable.Data(3,2),app.UITable.Data(3,3)];
        P4=[app.UITable.Data(4,1),app.UITable.Data(4,2),app.UITable.Data(4,3)];

        if isequal(P1,P2) || isequal(P1,P3) || isequal(P1,P4) || isequal(P2,P3) ||  isequal(P2,P4) || isequal(P3,P4)

            errordlg('vertices iguales')
        else

            vertex=[P1; P2 ;P3 ;P4];
            face= [1 2 3 nan; 2 3 4 nan; 1 2 4 nan; 1 3 4 nan];
            patch('Faces',face,'Vertices',vertex,'Facecolor',[0.8 0.8 1]);
            view(3);
            grid on
            
        end
```

Comment: If you provide a clear [mcve] then maybe someone can help you, without it your problem isn't very clear. If you had "thousands" of attempts at this then hopefully one of them is good enough to demonstrate what you're trying to achieve and highlight why `surf` isn't working as you hoped...